# Is my mac book pro suitable for CUDA?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

After visiting this page: 
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/

I don't know if my MacBook Pro is suitable for CUDA developement. After **About This Mac** I see this:

[image]

It does not seems to be a graphic card in this list:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

But I asked several times before buying this machine if it is capable for gpu stuffs. And I can correctly runs program that uses shaders. And, more important, I have installed CUDA driver and toolkit and they doesn't seems to give any error. But If I try to compile manually something with CUDA.. it doesn't work.

Comment: You can run CUDA in software mode, so that the code will be executed by your i5 CPU. This will not be very fast, but it might be enough to learn your first steps with CUDA. But note that the CPU behaves a little bit different from the GPU. So getting another machine with an NVIDIA GPU will be a good idea.

Comment: !! how can i do this?? please send me some link for emulating cuda with the CPU

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the device emulation mode seems to be deprecated in recent CUDA versions. Back in CUDA 3 this used to work. Sorry for getting your hopes up. The alternative seems to be gpuocelot, but that's Linux only so far. Sorry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your model has only the Intel HD 4000, so you can't use CUDA

Full specifications:
http://support.apple.com/kb/sp649

Comment: is there any possibility to change the graphic card or not?

Comment: sorry but is not possible

Answer (score 8):

About dialog displays only  the primary built-in device not the discrete, accelerated GPU. To be sure, run:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

in the terminal.

On my mac, the About dialog shows only on-chip Intel device, but the above command reveals the detail, also telling me that my Mac is equipped with the [AMD Radeon HD 6750M](http://www.amd.com/uk/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6750/Pages/amd-radeon-hd-6750-overview.aspx#2) which is OpenCL 1.1 capable. My mac is year older then yours.

All MBP devices have two cards.

> Graphics/Displays:
>
> ```
> Intel HD Graphics 3000:
>
>   Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 3000
>   Type: GPU
>   Bus: Built-In
>   VRAM (Total): 512 MB
>   Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
>   Device ID: 0x0126
>   Revision ID: 0x0009
>   gMux Version: 1.9.24
>   Displays:
>     Color LCD:
>       Display Type: LCD
>       Resolution: 1920 x 1200
>       Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
>       Main Display: Yes
>       Mirror: Off
>       Online: Yes
>       Built-In: Yes
>
> AMD Radeon HD 6750M:
>
>   Chipset Model: AMD Radeon HD 6750M
>   Type: GPU
>   Bus: PCIe
>   PCIe Lane Width: x8
>   VRAM (Total): 1024 MB
>   Vendor: ATI (0x1002)
>   Device ID: 0x6741
>   Revision ID: 0x0000
>   ROM Revision: 113-C0170L-573
>   gMux Version: 1.9.24
>   EFI Driver Version: 01.00.573
> ```

Comment: very nice answer thanks. and.. yes, only intel is showed

Answer (score 1):

I recently investigated the possibility of using the Macbook Retina as a CUDA development platform for scientific computing but came away disappointed with it's performance (as of Sep 22, 2014). I had purchased the more expensive model with the Nvidia graphics card for this specific purpose. See [Macbook Pro as a CUDA dev (not deployment) platform?](https://questionord.wordpress.com/2014/10/05/the-state-of-double-precision-floating-point-scientific-computing-on-the-nvidia-gt-750m-15-inch-apple-macbook-pro-retina-with-cuda-6-5-18-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9-5/) for details:

> **Conclusions**
>
> The Nvidia GT 750M card on the 15” Macbook pro Retina running Mac OS X 10.9.5 is not a great CUDA development/proofing platform if the user is interested mainly in double precision, floating point operations. This finding is in direct contrast to claims such as http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2012/06/14/new-macbook-pros-make-for-great-cuda-dev-platforms/

Answer (score 0):

Click on the System Report button and navigate to Hardware -> Graphics/Displays. If there's a discrete GPU that matches https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus, then you've met the System Requirements for CUDA.

Answer (score -4):

CUDA is only available on nVidia GPUs.

Comment: This answer adds nothing that hasn't already been said - in far greater detail.