# Which MacBook is actually CUDA capable?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, macos

There are quite a few links referring to whether a MacBook GPU is CUDA capable

- [Is my mac book pro suitable for CUDA?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93354/is-my-mac-book-pro-suitable-for-cuda)
- [Can I run CUDA on Intel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193242/can-i-run-cuda-on-intel)

Apart from the information stated in the above posts, is there even a MacBook capable of running CUDA?

Apple has been supporting Intel Graphics GPUs for quite some time. Is there a possible NVIDIA GPU for Macs to enable CUDA support?

Do the new MacBooks of 2015 (and the possible 2016) come with a CUDA capable GPU?

Comment: I'm going to link this to the CUDA question we already have. It has several answers showing exactly how to consult the CUDA capable list from NVIDIA.Speculating about new hardware for NVIDIA or Apple isn't on topic here, so this seems derivative of the existing question.

Comment: @bmike: Could *you* kindly give a probable answer based on your experience? Do existing 2015 MacBooks support CUDA?

Comment: The [selected answer is correct](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93356/5472). Your MacBook doesn't do any flavor of CUDA processing.

Comment: @bmike: At least that's one thing clear for me. Thank you. I'll be deleting this post soon then. By the way, as an expert in MacBooks, do you suppose NVIDIA would be supported in future MacBooks or not (due to reasons like power consumption and heat etc.)?

Comment: I wouldn't delete it - having duplicates helps with search terms. People asking similar questions to yours will know a thread exists. There's no penalty for having a post linked and closed to new answers. With an edit, it might make sense to even reopen it. I wasn't aware of 2014 using NVIDIA and should 2016 models be released, the on-topic  potential for reopening might be large.